# Concatenate two strings with a backslash iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and I need to have a string like "abc\123"

To have this I have tried doing:-

```
NSString *first = @"abc\\"; //Should escape
NSString *second= @"123";
NSString *combined= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",  first, second]; //which should give abc\123
```

But I get an output as `"abc\\123"`.

I am really stuck on this one. Any help is appreciated

Comment: just use "abc\" instead? or am i missing something

Comment: @Fonix That does not work and gives me an error `Missing terminating "" character`

Comment: NSLog(@"first = %ld, second = %ld, combined = %ld", first.length, second.length, combined.length); . just print out lengh of combined string You will see results is 7 :D

Comment: @larva Thanks for replying but could you elaborate in regards to my question I want to print `abc\123`

Comment: I don't know how you're printing the o/p, I'm getting `abc\123` as o/p of `NSLog(@"%@", combined);`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore you area right. I was trying to check the value by adding a watch to it. There it printed as abc\\

Comment: in debug value you may see String like combined = (__NSCFString *) @"abc\\123". But when use it really "abc\123" value, you can print out to test

Comment: or test it by displaying on an UILabel

Comment: What output you want?

Answer (score 1):

Backslash itself is the escape character so needs character to read ahead, you need to escape it.

This results same output you like.

```
NSString *first = @"abc\\";
```

You can check just by adding one more backshash @"abc\\\" gives you `missing character ""` runtime error.

```
NSString *first = @"abc\\";  // log results abc\
NSString *first = @"abc\\\\";  // log results abc\\
```

Can do by adding between format specifiers by following same backslash rule.

```
NSString *combined= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\\%@",  first, second];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the output issue, in fact, the string is correct.

```
let array = ["abc", "123"]
let separator = "\\"
separator.characters.count    //count=1
let x = array.joined(separator: "\\")
x.characters.count    //count = 7
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

> stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:

So in your case

```
NSString *first = @"abc\\"; //Should escape
NSString *second= @"123";
NSString *first = [first stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\"];
NSString *combined= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",  first, second];
```

So your result will be `abc\123`

Comment: Basically the OP's not wrong, he just seeing the debug area as it give `abc\\123`, but its really `abc\123`

Comment: May be you are giving a solution which doesn't solves the OP's problem. Please read comments on his post

Comment: @DHEERAJ My code was right. I was actually inspecting the value by adding a watch to it, there the value showed as "abc\\123", but when I printed it in the console, I got the right answer ie. "abc\123".